# Prove that $\sqrt{45}$ is irrational (using Euclid’s Lemma)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, irrational-numbers

Prove that $\sqrt{45}$ is irrational (using Euclid’s Lemma)

Assume $\sqrt{45}$ is rational.

By definition of rational : $\sqrt{p}=\frac{a}{b}$= $\sqrt{45}$=$\frac{a}{b}$ for some $a,b$ integers and $b≠0$

Let $a,b$ have no common divisor $>1$

By algebra, $45=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$

$45b^2=a^2$

Since $45b^2$ is divisible by 45 it follows that $a^2$ is divisible by 45. Then a is divisble by 45 by corollary, if p is a prime and p divides $a^2$, then p divides a... and this proof continues

My question is that when using Euclid's Lemma doesn't 45 have to be prime? since it isn't prime how would i get around this to make the last part of my proof complete to be able to finish and show a contradition

Comment: What is this $p$ you suddenly introduced?

Comment: p is supposed to be 45, but i didn't want to say for the corollary that if 45 is prime and 45 divides $a^2$ because 45 is not prime so i decided to put p instead... @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Start with $\sqrt{45}=3\sqrt{5}$ and proceed with the prime $5$. Or note that if $45\mid a^2$ then $5\mid a^2$ (because $5\mid45$) and proceed.

Comment: Note that if $45\mid a^2$, it is not always true that $45\mid a$. For example, $45\mid 225=15^2$, but it is not true that $45\mid 15$.

Comment: Right, i know that the corollary is only true if 45 was to be prime, which it isn't, which is why i'm having trouble what i'm supposed to do to finish the proof that the square root of 45 is irrational without being able to use that.

Comment: @Did so i'm just able to break the 45 into a prime number and continue with the same strategy i'm using? what will i do with the 3 hanging out? should i ignore the 3 or just have it follow the square root of 5 the whole time?

Comment: Hmmm... $3\sqrt{5}$ is rational if and only if $\sqrt{5}$ is $____$.

Comment: "My question is that when using Euclid's Lemma doesn't 45 have to be prime?" The radicand $x$ doesn't have to be prime; it's just that it shouldn't contain any perfect square, or the step from $x|a^2 \Rightarrow x|a$ fails to hold. Hence the answers below that start with getting the factor of 9 out to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sqrt{45}=3\sqrt{5}$. Thus it is enough to show that $\sqrt 5$ is irrati0nal. let
 $\sqrt{5}=\frac{a}{b}$ where $(a,b)=1$. then $5b^2=a^2\Rightarrow 5\vert a^2$ since $5$ is prime $5\vert a$ thus there is $k$ such that $a=5k\Rightarrow 5b^2=25k^2\Rightarrow b^2=5k^2 $ so $5\vert b$ contradiction with $(a,b)=1$

Comment: so right from the beginning i should break it up and then say showing squareroot of 5 is enough?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: I think that for this question-asker, an explicit step for why "$\sqrt{5}$ is irrational" implies "$3 \sqrt{5}$ is irrational" is appropriate.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins, dear it is can be easily checked by using $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\neq0$

Comment: @Razieh Noori: Yes, you should expand and add to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $5|a^2$ but $5$ is prime, then $5|a $.  If $5|a $ then $5|9b^2$, but $(5,9)=1$ implies $5|b^2$ and for the precedent reason $5|b $,in  other words $(a,b)\neq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ 45b^2 = a^2 $$
Since $5$ divides $45$, we conclude that $5$ divides $45b^2$ and then $5$ divides $a^2$. This means that $5$ divides $a$, and that $25$ divides $a^2$. Hence $25$ divides $45b^2$ or that $5$ divides $b^2$ which means $5$ divides $b$. Contradiction.